# wxpython crashing on windows 8 - python.exe stops working

Tags: python, crash, windows-8, wxpython

I had this code running perfectly on windows 7 - Python 2.7, once I changed to windows 8 it started crashing after a specific period of time or once it came back from a Callback. Can someone shed some light?

I get - Process finished with exit code -1073740771 (0xC000041D)

I load some data into the GUI from a call to a Callback, and when it tries to go back to the App it crashes.

I debuged it and once it does:

```
return _core_.PyApp_MainLoop(*args, **kwargs)
```

from the core module, it crashes.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Is this on the same machine? i.e. did you upgrade to windows 8 and keep your python (and wxpython) installs?

Comment: Nope, different machine. but I did transfer my files to this machine, so I am using the same Python - wxpython config on this computer.

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling python on the windows 8 machine, some configuration deep down in wxpython might be hiccuping if it isn't installed correctly

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that and come back in a while.

Comment: are you using threads? if you try and update the gui from a thread other than the main thread this type of thing happens

Comment: Not in this part of the code, no. But I do instantiate an object and initialize the data for that object from the GUI. But all these methods work fine and come back to the main GUI app. @wnnmaw, re-installed both python and wx, no luck. still same issue!

Comment: I did use wxGlade to create the GUI - don't know if that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was going on. During the load of data I was creating a dialog box do get the file path of the file with the data. When doing so, I was creating another instance of the App.

The code was doing:

```
app = wx.App(None)
```

but the GUI had already created one with the same name:

```
app = wx.App(0)
```

The strange thing is, on windows 7 there was no crash going on, but on windows 8 it crashed all the time.

Thanks for all the help!